# C - numbers not entering in the "if condition", dont know why

Tags: c

So, basically, I was instructed to make a function that asks the user for a size, and then creates an array with elements chosen by the user...
for example:    size:4 , input:10 20 30 40,  created array = {10,20,30,40}.
Then next step the user is to apply some function for this created array. Example:

For example, if the user chooses letter 'A' the function "add1" will be applied and all elements of the array will be increased in one unit, so with an input example of {10,20,30,40}, the output will be {11,21,31,41}.

My code is not working, why? Someone can help me? I've used the debugger and the function is not entering in the "if condition".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int* add1(int* array, int size)
{
    int *novo;
    novo = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *(novo + (i)) = *(array + i)+1;
    }
    return novo;
};


int* add2(int* array, int size)
{
    int *novo;
    novo = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *(novo + (i)) = *(array + i)+2;
    }
    return novo;
};



void print1(int* array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", *(array+i));
    }

};




int main(void)
{   int i, elemento, size;
    char *new;

    printf("Insert Size:\n");
    scanf("%i", &size);
    int newArray[size];
    printf("Insert Elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &elemento);
        newArray[i] = elemento;
    }

    printf("Select option:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &new);

    if (new == 'A') {
        int* result;
        result = add1(&newArray, size);
        print1(result, size);
    } else if (new == 'B') {
        int* result;
        result = add2(&newArray, size);
        print1(result, size);
    } else if (new == 'C') {
    } else if (new == 'D') {
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not use operator `==` to compare C strings (`char*`) but `strcmp`.

Comment: `new` is a character pointer. It should be a `char`. If you're using gcc or clang to compile, you should compile with options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: Btw, given the instructions, I think that you are supposed to modify the elements of the existing array, not create a new array.

Comment: `*(novo + (i)) = *(array + i)+1;` is the same as `novo[i] = array[i] + 1`, and the latter is lot easier to write, and read.

Answer (score 4):

1. Change:

   ```
   char *new;
   ```

to

```
char new;
```

as

```
 scanf(" %c", &new);
```

is expecting a character and as the code stands `new` is an undefined character pointer. So passing a pointer to a undefined pointer is not good.

PLEASE SWITCH ON YOUR COMPILER WARNINGS AND THIS WOULD BE PICKED UP!

2. `new` is not a good variable name. As it leads to confusion with C++ keyword
3. Check the return values for `scanf`- see the manual page for that
4. Perhaps using `switch` instead of `if new == 'A' .....`